# Best way to reset ActiveRecord Attribute with a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a counter in my model that I want to give the user the ability to
reset it, I'm wondering what's the best way to achieve this. I can think of
two ways:

1. By a custom controller action.

   Simple and easy but I can't decide which HTTP verb to use. I can make the
   case that it should be a `GET` because the user clicks a link that reset
   the counter and the result are always the same, i.e. counter
   becomes 0. But it could also be a `POST`/`PATCH` since we are modifying
   something on the server but `POST`/`PATCH` requires a form which leads to
   the other way.
2. By a link that submits an edit form with the counter reset to 0 without
   the user seeing the form.

   I like this solution because it can be done with RESTful controller
   methods. But I have no idea how to do that with Rails, or even if it's
   possible.

So which is "Rails Way" to do this? and how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating a custom action, another approach is to create a well-named controller and stick to the RESTful controller method names.

**config/routes.rb**

```
resource :counter_reset, only: [:create]
```

**app/controllers/counter_reset_controller.rb**

```
class CounterResetController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # reset your counter
  end
end
```

Then `POST` to `counter_reset_path` in your view

Personally, I would use `button_to` — this generates a single button that submits to the URL; it performs a `POST` operation by default. If you don't like the button style, you can switch to using `link_to`; however, keep in mind that if a user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fallback to using `GET`.

```
<%= button_to "Reset counter!", counter_reset_path %>
<%= link_to "Reset counter!", counter_reset_path, method: :post %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

**Update:**

If you prefer not to create a new controller, you can create a new route that maps to a custom action in your existing controller:

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :counters do
  post :reset, to: "counters#reset"
end
```

**app/controllers/counters_controller.rb**

```
class CountersController < ApplicationController
  def reset
    # reset your counter
  end
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= button_to "Reset counter!", counter_reset_path %>
```

Comment: `button_to` is exactly what I was looking for. Can't I just use `button_to` with the existing controller rather than making a new controller just for one button?

Comment: If you prefer not to create a new controller to reset the counter, you can define a new route that maps to a custom action in your existing controller; however, you'd be deviating from RESTful controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need a form, for me i would add a new action, it would look something like this ( of course depends on how your current routing looks like )

```
/user/:id/counter/reset # with action = post
```

And the link is very simple, you just create a `link_to` and add a `method: :post` which will add a `data-method: :post` in the html, the rest will be handled by the unobtrusive js.

The reason I don't recommend the form method, is users might use it to update different attributes that you might not want to update, or at least even change the counter to whatever number they want, I prefer the specific number to be defined in the controller not the view/form.